# Programming issue. Lag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive been having some issues programming in unity with c#. I am trying to request an interstitial AD when i start the game so i can show it when the player has died 5 times. The issue is that when i get to the 5th death the ad won't show. and when I try requesting the ad when the level starts it gets laggy and still doesn't show.

This is my code. It seems right.

```
void Update(){
    if (clicks >= 5) {
        RequestInterstitial();
        Debug.Log("Got 5 clicks");
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded()){
            Debug.Log("interstitial loaded");
            interstitial.Show();
            clicks = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** After modifying my code, I now get the error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ADS.ADMobsGameplay.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ADS/ADMobsGameplay.cs:28)

Line 28 corresponds to `if (interstitial.IsLoaded()){` in the following code:

```
void Update(){
    if (clicks >= 5) {
        Debug.Log("Got 5 clicks");
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded()){
            Debug.Log("interstitial loaded");
            interstitial.Show();
            clicks = 0;
        }else{
            RequestInterstitial();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do any of the logs get hit? What is the flow here? Please provide more code if you can.

Comment: Yes they all do which is why I'm confused. It shows 5 clicks then interstitial loaded and it resets to 0 because if i die 5 times again it will get requested. Im thinking its a request and show error. I might request at the wrong time.? When the player dies it updated the clicks variable and the ads show when the player dies but should i request the ad when the level starts? Or when the player dies? I know it needs time to load the request before showing but if i request at the start of the level its really laggy.

Comment: Can you provide more code? I think the issue might be in code other than this part

Comment: Sure. Im get this error now.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ADS.ADMobsGameplay.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ADS/ADMobsGameplay.cs:28)

which is at if (interstitial.IsLoaded()){


  void Update(){
   if (clicks >= 5) {
    Debug.Log("Got 5 clicks");
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded()){
     Debug.Log("interstitial loaded");
     interstitial.Show();
     clicks = 0;
    }else{
     RequestInterstitial();
    }
   }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Requesting the Interstitial over and over again. Just run the `RequestInterstitial` method at the beginning of the program (and make sure it only runs the method once).
Then, in whatever method you increment clicks, simply add something like this to the end:

```
int clicksRequired = 5;
int currentClicksRequired = 5;
if(clicks > currentClicksRequired){
    Debug.Log("Got 5 Clicks");
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded()){
        Debug.Log("interstitial loaded");
        interstitial.Show();
        RequestInterstitial();
        clicks = 0;
        currentClicksRequired = clicksRequired;
    }else{
        Debug.Log("interstitial not loaded, skipping to next click");
        currentClickRequired ++;
    }
}
```

Once clicks reaches 5, it will check if the interstitial has been loaded. If so, it shows the interstitial, requests another interstitial, resets clicks at 0, and then moves on. If the interstitial is not loaded yet, it makes you wait till the 6th click, or the 7th, etc, until the interstitial is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shown NullReferenceException error in yours comment: this is first issue that can provide lags. Second - it is really weird to put some counting logic into Update function - update works every frame - so it`s second possible lag issue. Third Debug.Log function is not a lightweight, into Update function it will be third possible lag issue